# nvd3 python and axis

Tags: python, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm going to use nvd3 in python to build a linechart. Here is the code:

```
from nvd3 import lineChart
chart = lineChart(name="lineChart", x_is_date=True, x_axis_format="%Y")

xdata = [599644800000,694252800000,788947200000,883641600000,1167638400000,1199174400000,1230796800000,1262332800000,1357027200000]
ydata = [26.2, 22.4, 17.7, 14.8, 9.29, 8.08, 7.48, 6.96, 5.5]

extra_serie = {"tooltip": {"y_start": "There are ", "y_end": " calls"}}
chart.add_serie(y=ydata, x=xdata, name='Current Smokers ', extra=extra_serie, **kwargs1)
chart
```

and here is the chart:
[image]

I have three questions:

1. x-axis has 9 elements but the chart is showing just 3 of them. How can I change the code in order to show all 9 elements?
2. The type of y-axis elements are percentage. How can I add % to the y-axis?
3. It looks nvd3 does not accept date in the regular format and I had to convert them millisecond and is a bit annoying. How can I get rid of those milliseconds date format and simply use 1998, 1995 and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used NVD3 in Python but I could point you out how its done using the JavaScript library. Here's the answers to your questions.

1. By default NVD3 reduces the amount of ticks rendered in the chart based on the chart width.

   a) One way of showing more ticks on your chart XAxis is to increase the width of the chart. Maybe not the best way but it works.

   `chart = lineChart(..., width="500")`.

   b) Another way is by defining the points you want displayed on the chart and passing it as an array to the chart. [Check line 29 here](http://jsfiddle.net/shabeer90/1ztx5syg/).

   `chart.xAxis.tickValues(tickArr);`

   *Keep in mind the tick labels might overlap depending on the width of the chart and the amount you are trying to display in a chart*
2. Append the `%` at the end of the tick when rendered.

   ```
   chart.yAxis.tickFormat(function (d) {
       var format = d3.format(",.f");
       return format(d) + '%';
   });
   ```
3. You can pass the date as it is `e.g: 1998-02-11`  More information on [date & time parsing here](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Formatting.md#format)

   ```
   var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
   format.parse("1998-02-11"); // returns a Date
   format(new Date(1998, 02, 11)); // returns a string
   ```

Hope this help you.